# Codenameone:Unable to set floating hint to textfield

Tags: codenameone

When I clicked on textfield in my application I get following errors:

```
[EDT] 0:0:8,230 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Component is already contained in Container:
    Container[x=29 y=124 width=245 height=71, layout = TableLayout,
    scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [TextField, TextField]]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container:
    Container[x=29 y=124 width=245 height=71, layout = TableLayout,
    scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [TextField, TextField]]
```

I want to set Floating hint to my textField.Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Comment: You should post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the text field to the container and then wrapped it again in the floating hint. You should instead add the floating hint. E.g. you did something like this:

```
myContainer.add(myTextField);
myContainer.add(new FloatingHint(myTextField));
```

You should have done just this:

```
myContainer.add(new FloatingHint(myTextField));
```

Comment: can you tell me. how i can do it with Gui builder in code name one

Comment: I did .. @Override
    protected void onLogin_TxtLoginAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    
     findContainerBody().add(findContainerLoginRow2().add(new FloatingHint(findTxtLogin())));
    
    }

Comment: `findTxtLogin()` implies you have taken a text field that you already added to the UI hierarchy in the GUI builder which means it already has a parent. You need to either remove it beforehand or use a new text field which means you should not construct that specific element within the GUI builder

Comment: That's GUI builder it's hard to give a sample to that. There is sample code for the TextField and floating hint the problem is you are applying it to a component that you already added to the UI via the GUI builder. I'm not sure how I can provide a code sample to "don't drag that into there".

Comment: any other solution for that?? what should i do for getting floating hint with gui builder??

Comment: How many solutions do you need? Just don't add the text field and add it thru the `FloatingHint` is that too hard?